# Determine if elements in an ArrayList are consecutively ordered

Tags: java

> Write a method `isConsecutive` that accepts an ArrayList of integers as
>   a parameter and returns true if the list contains a sequence of
>   consecutive integers and false otherwise. Consecutive integers are
>   integers that come one after the other in ascending order, as in 5, 6,
>   7, 8, 9, etc. For example, if a variable called list stores the values
>   `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, then the call of `list.isConsecutive()` should
>   return true. If the list instead stored `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13]` then
>   the call should return false because the numbers 7 and 12 are not
>   consecutive. The list `[3, 2, 1]` might seem to be consecutive, but the
>   elements appear in reverse order, so the method would return false in
>   that case. Any list with fewer than two values should be considered to
>   be consecutive. You may assume that the list passed is not null.

Wondering which better ways there are to do this, and how to improve my future code.

```
public boolean isConsecutive(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == (list.get(i + 1) - 1)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return list.size() - 1 == count || list.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a counter in your code:

```
public boolean isConsecutive(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i) != list.get(i + 1) - 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

As a next step, you can change the loop to start at 1 instead of 0, so that the loop condition becomes simpler.

```
public boolean isConsecutive(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i - 1) + 1 != list.get(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The specification does not require the algorithm to be constant-time (it's not used for cryptography), therefore it should be OK to return as soon as you know the answer.

To be extra correct, you could detect integer overflows:

```
int prev = list.get(i - 1);
if (prev != list.get(i) /* mismatch */ || prev + 1 < prev /* overflow */) {
    return false;
}
```

If the requirements were to change that you may only access each list element once, you would need to remember the previous value.

```
public boolean isConsecutive(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
    if (!it.hasNext()) {
        return true;
    }

    int prev = it.next();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        int curr = it.next();
        if (prev + 1 != curr /* mismatch */ || prev + 1 < prev /* overflow */) {
            return false;
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
    return true;
}
```